# Android How to add webview with button on same activity

Tags: android, button, webview

I am building an Android app and I am newbie.
I have 3 button on my main activity which each button loads different urls.
I want to add a WebView url on top of buttons. Buttons are already on bottom.

**check my main activity code -**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AlbumButton);

    // album button
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Start AlbumActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    AlbumActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

    // about button
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AboutButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class));
        }
    });

    // contact button 
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ContactButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class));
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**I dont know where to add webview.** 
**Here is my activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
tools:context="com.mayanktaker.moderncolourlab.MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/home_view_browser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/home_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AlbumButton"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:text="@string/AlbumButton"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="425dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AboutButton"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/AboutButton"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="425dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ContactButton"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/ContactButton"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="425dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new and still learning basics. 
Please help me to add the webview on this activity. So when app opens, i can see webview load and 3 buttons on bottom. (Currently getting webview blank white area and buttons on bottom)
Thanks

Comment: Your WebView does not have an initial URL to load and hence nothing to show. You can load a default URL or show HTML string saying something like please select either of the below buttons to load.

Comment: I dont want buttons to load ulr here. Buttons are already loading url on other activity. I want to load webview on this activity. Just above the buttons. I setup the webview on xml(see  there) but i dont know how to call or load a webview url on this MainActivity.

Comment: If you are sending the URL to another activity, why do you want to show the content in this activity. Can you explain the scenario more?

Comment: In my app main activity showing a webview where i want to load an internal html file via url and below that i am showing three buttons. Each button loading activities already. I want to show animated content from an html file via webview above three buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         if (Constants.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            WebView htmlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.home_view_browser);
            htmlWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
            WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
            webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
            htmlWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
        } else {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AlbumButton);

        // album button
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start AlbumActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        AlbumActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        // about button
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AboutButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class));
            }
        });

        // contact button 
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ContactButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    /*isNetworkAvailable function*/
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        /* if no network is available networkInfo will be null, otherwise check if we are connected*/
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Comment: web_contact giving error (red color) so I changed to this - `WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` and getting `Error:(35, 16) error: non-static method getSettings() cannot be referenced from a static context` and when iam removing this line, code is working but url opening on new window, not in our webview layout. :(

Comment: Yes. This is the solution. Thanks alot. :)

Comment: Can we show 'No Internet Connection" here if net is not connected ?

Comment: @Mayanktaker check updated code not 'No Internet Connection'

Answer (score 0):

You can load the URLs in the following manner:

```
String linkToUrl = "https://www.google.com";
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.home_view_browser);
webView.loadUrl(linkToUrl);
```

Does it help?

Comment: I will check this on my activity. Can you tell me where to put this code? Below buttons codes ?

Comment: This needs to be put inside the button click handlers.

Comment: This opening a new browser page. Not in our webview. :|

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file add the following:

```
   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/webViewContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"/>
```

....In your activity add the following method

```
 public void addWebView(View container){

        WebView webView=new WebView();

        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollContainer(true);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        container.addView(webView);


}
```

Finally in button onClick method call:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
              FrameLayout layout=findViewById(R.id.webViewContainer);

             layout.removeAllViews();
             addWebView(layout);
             webView.loadUrl(YOUR_URL);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I dont want this one to load on button xlick. I want to load the url when main activity opens. I will try this code however. Thanks.

Comment: Yea you can just put the code from onClick to onCreate of activity. Let me know if it works and accept answer if it does.

Comment: Its not working. :( Where to put framelayout ? Above Webview or above button in xml? And when im putting framelayout code in oneCreate of activity, it also giving me error. Red color FrameLayout.

Comment: what does the error say?  Press Alt Enter and you get suggestions on how to correct. You should put FrameLayout anywhere you want it in your xml. That will be where webview is shown. If you want it on full page then make it full page.